# Extract complete URL from a link

Tags: scrapy, playwright-python

I am scrapping amanzon.co.in using scrapy-playwright. I am able to extract description, rating and price of desired item.  However for going to next page I want to extract href for Next Page button at the bottom of the page.

Thru scrapy-playwright python code I am able to extract href of next button as : href="/s?k=Soap+for+men&page=2"

When I extract URL using the browser, it appears like : https://www.amazon.in/s?k=soap+for+men&page=2&crid=1A43B14UY65X0&qid=1671472636&sprefix=soap+for+men%2Caps%2C262&ref=sr_pg_1

How do I get generate complete URL from the link including crid extracted thru code ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: How did you get the value `href="/s?k=Soap+for+men&page=2"` could you share the code?

Comment: you probably need to get the token from the cookies passed when the next page button is clicked.